# Unable to remove bootstrap date picker from textbox

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bind, bootstrap-datepicker, unbind

My scenario is that i have couple of textboxes
 i manually add bootstrap date picker with that text boxes manually in jquery

```
$('#dataRange input').addClass('datepicker');
$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date()).focus();
```

and then when i try to remove or unbind it

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
$(".datepicker").unbind('focus');
$('#dataRange input').removeClass('datepicker');
```

then i can not change back to date picker with first code , date picker dropdown box do not show up :(

Comment: wouldn't removing just the class be enough?

Comment: @madalinivascu nope

Comment: `i manually add bootstrap datetime picker` .. but i see only `datepicker`

Comment: @Novice updated my question :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its working here Please see this. I think you are missing some events. I have added **two buttons** for example **bind and unbind** and on click event I have bind and unbind respectively datepicker and its working. Check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sojitrar88/ymwpon5f/)

```js
$('#dataRange input').addClass('datepicker');
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date()).focus();
            $(".unbind").on("click", function () {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
            });
            $(".bind").on("click", function () {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date()).focus();
            });
```

```html
<div id="dataRange">
            <input type="text" name="datein" value="">
        </div>
        <button class="unbind">unbind</button>
        <button class="bind">bind</button>
```

Comment: there is issue in your snippet , unable to run , issue at line # 17

Answer (score 0):

Rakesh Sojitra is resolver. I just make his code to snip for you.

```js
$(function () {
                $('#dataRange input').addClass('datepicker');
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",autoclose:true}).datepicker("setDate", new Date()).focus();
                $(".unbind").on("click", function () {
                    $('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
                });
                $(".bind").on("click", function () {
                    $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date()).focus();
                });
            });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <div id="dataRange">
            <input type="text" name="datein" value="">
        </div>
        <button class="unbind">unbind</button>
        <button class="bind">bind</button>
</form>
```